# Java JFrame Title bar disappears in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, java

I have placed the java application's jar file path in `.profile` in ubuntu to make it executed at the startup. But unfortunately the title bars disappears on both `JFrame` windows.

I have made it sure that i check `undecorated` value to be `false` but yet the problem persists. Can someone here please guide to right direction.

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 LTS with 4 GB RAM. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some relevant code and we can figure out the problem. It's working well on Windows OS?

Comment: @Benny Haven't tested it on Widows since it is developed for Ubuntu only.